# Passing an Error object to function makes its message undefined

Tags: javascript, error-handling

when passing an Error object to a function at least the message becomes undefined, why?
example:

```
//prints "test"
console.log(new Error("test").message);
function errorPrinter(err){
    console.log(err.message);
}
//prints undefined:
errorPrinter(new Error("test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

On my side it's working perfectly as expected:

- The first `console.log` logs "test"
- The second one logs "test" from inside the `errorPrinter` function
- The function returns `undefined` because nothing has been returned

[image: See example]

Comment: Ok yes it works for some reason it does not work when the error is catched in a catch block